# CSS Gridlayout Child not adhering to grid-template

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a data input page using CSS gridlayout where the `content-section` grid has a top section containing the inputs and a bottom section containing the data results already in the database.  The top section is divided into two grid columns.  But when I add my inputs the top section does not adhere to the `grid-template-columns` or `grid-template-rows` values.
I added a coloured border to each of the grids to see which grids are not following the CSS  class attributes. As clearly can be seen from my code snippet the `section-top` (yellow border) and its `col1` (green border) along with `col2` (green border) children is not following the set attributes. 
The `section-top` should only be 40% its parent the `content-section` (red border) and the children `col1` along with `col2` must display as two evenly sized columns within the top section.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Nunito,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    background-color: #3399FF;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #858796;
}
.main-grid-data-section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 80% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 85% auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "title title title"
    "smaller-header smaller-header smaller-header"
    "sidebar sidebar sidebar"
    ". content-section ."
    "footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 1px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
.smaller-header {
    grid-area: smaller-header;
}
.content-section {
    grid-area: content-section;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 40% auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "section-top"
    "section-bottom";
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(255, 51, 51);
}
.section-top {
    grid-area: section-top;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
    "col1 col2";
    align-self: start;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(252, 255, 51);
}

.section-bottom {
 grid-area: section-bottom;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 2px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgb(255, 160, 51);
}
.col1 {
 grid-area: col1;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgb(58, 255, 51);
}
.col2 {
 grid-area: col2;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgb(58, 255, 51);
}
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 30% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
    "login-footer-grid login-footer-grid login-footer-grid"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/test.css">
    </head>
<body>
<!-- Main grid layout -->
<div class="main-grid-data-section">
    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <div class="smaller-header">
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
    <!-- Content data grid -->
    <div class="content-section">
        <!-- Data input section -->
        <div class="section-top">
            <form id="grading" class="form-container">
                <div class="col1">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Document number" id="docnumber" name="docnumber">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Bruto waarde" id="gross" name="gross">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Bin hoeveelheid" id="cnt" name="cnt">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Bin gewig" id="bin" name="bin">
                </div>
                <div class="col2">
                    <input type="number" id="cj" name="cj">
                    <input type="number" id="cb" name="cb">
                    <input type="number" id="cm" name="cm">
                    <input type="number" id="sj" name="sj">
                    <input type="number" id="sb" name="sb">
                    <input type="number" id="sm" name="sm">
                    <input type="number" id="ind" name="ind">
                    <input type="number" id="nv" name="nv">
                    <input type="number" id="moist" name="moist">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Data show section -->
        <div class="section-bottom">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <!--Footer-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried removing the children template-areas attribute and setting the columns as template-columns only, it did not work.
Can someone please point out to me what attribute or property is causing this problem?

Comment: Can you try reducing the code you provided to only the relevant pieces, you have 4 grids in your code, the first one `.main-grid-data-section` you forgot to give some element their grid-area names. And in `.section-top` you defined 2 columns but you only have one grid item (form) i think you wanted to make the form a grid, if not set form to [`display:contents`](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Acontents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you say

> As clearly can be seen from my code snippet the section-top (yellow border) and its col1 (green border) along with col2 (green border) children is not following the set attributes.

But col1 and col2 are not children of section top, they are grand-children of it.

You can set the style that you are applying to section-top to the form grading, and then the grid styles will work

Comment: Thank you, that solves it.  I always thought that the grid only conforms to the class template-area set within an element as in my case the form has a class with no display attributes.  Does this mean that all children elements of a grid parent inherit the grid attribute if not set?  Also, if a grid container has more inputs than it can contain, will it burst out of its set display attribute?

Comment: About your first question, all children elements of a grid become grid-items. There is nothing that you need to do to get this to happen. But there is nothing really special about this at the children level, may be the only noticeable thing is that they become "blockified". About your second question, probably you mean what happens when the is more elements that templete areas. In this case, grid-auto-columns or grid-auto-rows will be added. It depends on grid-auto-flow value.